# If $P$ is prime then is $P+6$ prime?

Tags: number-theory

I would like to ask if it's proven that: "If $P\geq5$ is prime then $P+6$ or $P+12$ or $P+18$ or $P+30$ is prime"? If not is it likely to be true?

Comment: I assume you've already checked all the primes up to some value?  How large?

Comment: The first counterexample is $463$.

Comment: I've looked at the first 10000 primes.

Comment: @math: Then apparently you made a mistake...?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311652/im-trying-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-set-of-composite-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: For what it's worth the title question is entirely different from the question body.

Comment: Slightly extending the answer below : The difference between consecutive primes is not bounded. So, even if you add finite many expressions of the form $\ P+a\ $ with positive integer $\ a\ $, there still exists a counterexample , in fact infinite many.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $$2|(31! + 2), 3|(31! + 3), 4 | (31! + 4), \dots ,31|(31!+31).$$
Therefore, there are 30 consecutive composite numbers beginning at $31! + 2$. Now look at the biggest prime smaller than $31!+2$. It is followed by at least 30 non-primes, so we have a counterexample.