# Behavior of difference of prime numbers when $n$ approaches infinity

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

The following question is part of a question I had to solve for my masters exam.

> Consider $S=\{s_n =p_{n+1}- p_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Prove that sup $S=\infty$.

Intutively I guessed it and Tried using prime number theorem and L Hopital rule but it comes out to be very lenghty and still indeterminant.

So, I am looking for altenative rigorious method.

Kindly tell how to prove it.

Thanks!!

Comment: You just need to show that you can find consecutive primes with arbitrarily large gaps. A standard way to show this would be to consider the numbers near factorials $n!$

Comment: The answers here might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311652/im-trying-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-set-of-composite-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: For every possible distance between successive primes $k=p_{i+1}-p_i$, the factorial $(k+1)!$ has at least $k$ composite numbers in a row in the interval $[(k+1)!+2,(k+1)!+k+1]$.  This same approach can be applied using a number like $(k+1)\#$ as well, with a small amount of logic to obtain the result.