# Prove that there are no prime numbers in $[n! + 2; n! + n]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am struggling trying to prove that there are no prime numbers in $[n! + 2; n! + n]$ gap. Could someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, what attempts have you made

Comment: Hint: Consider a specific number $n!+k$ and find a divisor.

Comment: Hint: For all k in the given range, there will be a common term between k and n!+k.

Comment: This is the standard way to prove that the prime gaps are unbounded. This probably has been already asked here.

Comment: This has been discussed here many times before, for example [this previous Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311654/3111) to a Question about trying to find the longest sequence of composite numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to find the longest consecutive set of composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311652/im-trying-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-set-of-composite-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd seeming things happen for $n=1,2$ so I will explicitly restrict my answer to $n>2$

To flesh out the answer given by fleablood: For $2< k \le n$ we have $k>1$, and every number in the interval is of the form $n!+k$ for $n,k$ as defined. Also, since $n!$ has every $k$ as an explicit factor, but not its only factor, every number $\frac{n!}{k}=a_k>1$ is an integer.

Thus for every $k$ as defined, $\frac{n!+k}{k}=(a_k+1) \Rightarrow n!+k=k\cdot (a_k+1)$. Since $n!+k$ has two factors, each greater than $1$, it is not prime, and this is true for every $k$. So no number in the interval is prime.

Answer (score 0):

No prime is in the gap $ [ ] $
$$(n!+2)[ n!+3,n!+4,n!+5,\dots \dots , n!+n-1](n!+n)$$
The number of terms in the sequence is $(n!+n-1)-(n!+3)+1 = n-3$
$$(n!+2)[ n!+3,n!+4,n!+5,\dots \dots , n!+n-1](n!+n)$$
Basically the sequence are all sums of $n!$, since $n!$ is the product of numbers less than it, therefore $ n! +2k$ cannot be prime, $n!+3k$ cannot also be prime,$\dots \dots$, $n!+m\cdot k$ cannot also be prime

What about the case when of $n!+ k$, when $k$ is prime, if $k$ is $\lt n$, means it's multiples are contained in $n!$ then the sum $n!+k$ is not prime

What about $n!+k$, where $k$ is prime and $k \gt n $, here the sum would be a prime number
$$(n!+2)[ n!+3,n!+4,n!+5,\dots \dots , n!+n-1](n!+n)$$
In our sequence, the largest value of $k$ is $n-1$, it happens at the last sequence $n!+\{ n-1\} $ but $n-1 \lt n$

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is realize that if $k< n$ then $k|n!$ so $k|n! + k$ and if $k\ne 1$ then $n! + k$ is not prime.

Comment: Thank you so much!