# Prime numbers and their largest known difference

Tags: prime-numbers

What is the largest difference between two consecutive prime numbers?
E.g 37-31=6

So which is the largest margin that exists between two consecutive prime numbers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311652/im-trying-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-set-of-composite-numbers) is another duplicate.  I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Yes I've identified my question as an inquiry on prime gaps thank you

Comment: Do you mean what the largest KNOWN gap between consecutive prime numbers (or at least probable prime numbers) is ?

Comment: Yes @Peter that is what I mean