# Prove that exist $n$ consecutive numbers each one with at least one prime factor repeted $t$ times

Tags: elementary-number-theory

"Given $n,t \in \mathbb{N}$ prove that exist $n$ consecutive natural numbers with each one of them having at least one prime factor repeted $t$ times."

Well, at a first glance I couldn't do anything, so I found this:

[How do I prove that for every positive integer $n$, there exist $n$ consecutive positive integers, each of which is composite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030204/how-do-i-prove-that-for-every-positive-integer-n-there-exist-n-consecutive)

And my point is, with the numbers $i+(n+1)!$ with $1<i\leq n+1$, I get $n$ consecutive composite numbers. And if I do $i+((n+1)!)^t$ will I get what I was asked for?

Comment: Here $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: This approach will not work.  Just try it for a small case like $n=1, t=2$.  You don’t even get one consecutive value with the desired property.

Comment: Use the [Chinese Remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) with a suitable set of prime powers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}m&\equiv&0\pmod{2^k}\\ m+1&\equiv&0\pmod{3^k}\\ \ldots &\equiv &\ldots \\ m+n-1 &\equiv &0\pmod{p_n^k}\end{array}\right.$$
has a solution $m\leq (2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n)^k\approx e^{kn}$ which is associated with an interval $[m,m+n-1]$ of integers fulfilling the wanted constraint.